# How to configure SDK WebAssembly Manifest <WriteLinesToFile /> so that multiple files are passed

Tags: blazor-webassembly, multi-project

I have three webassembly projects one of them referencing the other two.

But web assembly manifest prevent the project to build, says:

```
 MSB4094    "C:\Users\..\Desktop\BlazorUI2 - Copy\Client1\obj\Debug\net8.0\service-
    worker\service-worker.js;C:\Users\..\Desktop\BlazorUI2 - Copy\Client2\obj\Debug\net8.0
    \service-worker\service-worker.js;C:\Users\..\Desktop\BlazorUI2 - Copy\BlazorUI2\obj\Debug
    \net8.0\service-worker\service-worker.js" is an invalid value for the "File" parameter of the
     "WriteLinesToFile" task. Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type 
    "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".  BlazorUI2   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100
    \Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets
    \Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets    163
```

I want to change this config in sdk manifest, so that the project pass multiple files to this:

```
<WriteLinesToFile
  File="@(_BuildServiceWorkerFile->'%(Identity)')"
  Lines="/*Manifest version: $(_BuildServiceWorkerAssetsManifestVersion)*/"
  Condition="'$(_BuildServiceWorkerAssetsManifestVersion)' != ''" />
```

how to do this?